# Strictification of the squaring monad

Tags: ct.category-theory

It pertains to the classical literature on the subject (see e.g. [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/04/on_two-dimensional_monad_theory.html)) the fact that an accessible 2-monad $T$ on a 2-category $\cal K$ induces an adjunction
$$
\mathbf{Strict}\text{-}T\text{-}\textbf{Alg}\leftrightarrows \mathbf{Pseudo}\text{-}T\text{-}\textbf{Alg}
$$
between strict $T$-algebras and pseudo $T$-algebras. This means that for every morphism $(A,a)\to (B,b)$ of $T$-algebras where the relevant diagrams commute up to invertible 2-cells, there is a new $T$-algebra $(A^\text{s}, a^\text{s})$ with a *strict* morphism $(A^\text{s}, a^\text{s}) \to (B,b)$.

> What does this construction become when $T : {\bf Cat}\to {\bf Cat}$ is the 2-monad that sends a small category $A$ into the category $A^\textbf{2}$ of its arrows (for sure a finitary monad on a locally finitely presentable category)?

Comment: Three irresponsible blind guesses: either$${\bf Cat}^\textbf{2}\leftrightarrows{\bf Cat}/\textbf{2}$$or$${\bf Cat}^\textbf{2}\leftrightarrows{\bf Cat}//\textbf{2}$$or$${\bf Cat}/\textbf{2}\leftrightarrows{\bf Cat}//\textbf{2}$$(here "//" stands for hypercomma, a. k. a. lax slice)

Comment: A single naive question: are you saying that ${\bf Cat}^2\cong {\bf Cat}/2$? I've never noticed this.

Comment: Wait, this is not the only problem. What do these three adjunctions denote? No one of the categories in your guess is the category of algebras for the squaring monad :-)

Comment: Re first - lhs embeds into rhs as fibrations over $\bf2$. Re second - I believe all three admit adjunctions to $\bf Cat$ inducing the $(\_)^{\bf2}$ monad.

Comment: ...that said, let me reiterate that the comment was irresponsible :D

Comment: The only reference I can find is Lack's "companion". Unfortunately I'm not able to see what is the argument to build $A^\text{s}$, which in his notes is only sketched. What is the best way to summon him and ask for help, in your opinion?

Comment: Other references are the original Blackwell-Kelly-Power "Two-dimensional monad theory" and Lack's "Codescent objects and coherence".  The construction proceeds by 2-colimits in strict $T$-algebras.

Comment: It is precisely "Codescent" that I'm trying to read, but I got stuck in the definition of the codescent object which happens in three steps. I'm referring to notation of the paper, in particular the paragraph that precedes Prop. 2.1. After having built the coinserter $(w_1, \bar w_1)$ Lack says "then [we build] the coequifier $w_2$ of $(\bar w_1 r)(\bar w_1 e)$ and $(w_1\gamma)(w_1\delta)$". But now the composition $(\bar w_1 r)(\bar w_1 e)$ doesn't even make sense!

Comment: Just an à propos: obviously "codescent" shall be banned, and replaced by "ascent" :D

Comment: I agree, and by the way resolved myself that there is an annoying typo in Lack's paper. But I think I'm able to circumvent the issue, fortunately. This shouldn't prevent anybody from giving me an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strict algebra of the squaring monad is precisely a [strict factorization system](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+factorization+system). A normal pseudo-algebra (unit holds strictly) is precisely an orthogonal factorization system. See [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(93)90171-O). The pseudo-algebras will differ by first replacing a morphism by an isomorphic morphism before factoring it.

So that's what the pseudo-algebras look like. You can read off from this a description of the strictified monad.